# What are the themes/styles used for theming the overflow dropdown menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I am trying to theme the overflow dropdown menu but I am having trouble finding the correct themes and styles for this part of the actionbar.

I am currently looking in the following files:

> https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml
>   https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

Could anyone enlighten me please?

Comment: any picture for the menu ? ? ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find what I wanted by creating a bogus holo theme here:

> http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Then I just looked at the example inside the zip file and updated my themes/styles files as so:

```
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyApp.Theme.PopupMenu</item>
<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyApp.Theme.DropDownListView</item>

<style name="MyApp.Theme.PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/theme_menu_popup_background</item>
</style>

<style name="MyApp.Theme.DropDownListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/theme_menu_popup_selector</item>
</style>
```

I would like to know how to totally overhaul everything but it seems I can only ever manage to drip feed my app with those essential theme/style specific bits because it takes soooo long to find the necessary styling syntax. If only there was an easier way.

Of course I have no idea how to position the `ListPopupWindow` or even change the color of the text but it's good enough for now.